# How can I cut image diagonally in react-native?

Tags: react-native, styling

I am developing a social networking app in react-native. I wanted to know if it is possible to cut `<Image>` in the way shown in the image:

[image]

If yes, can you provide me some example or any hints to implement this.

[Reference for android](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/create-diagonal-cut-view-in-android-5a376eca6a1c#.qk7kfffpp)

Comment: Did you get the desired view?

Answer (score 4):

You could display a white triangle shaped `View` on top of your image

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={require('./images.jpg')}  >
        <View style={[styles.triangle]} /></Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  triangle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: '#fff',
  },
  img: { 
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

apply this to your style tag of view,don forgot to import Dimensions from 'react-native'

```
triangleCorner: {
        left:0,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftWidth:Dimensions.get('window').width,
        borderBottomWidth: 80,
        borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
        borderBottomColor: 'white'
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

very old post but I found one solution, I use inline style for more easy example:

```html
 <ImageBackground
            style={{
              left: 0,
              width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 10,
              height: 220,
              justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'
            }}
            source={{ uri: header.banner }}></ImageBackground>
          <View style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderRightWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            borderLeftWidth: 0,
            borderBottomWidth: 100,
            borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
            borderRightColor: 'transparent',
            borderBottomColor: '#fff',
          }} />
```